# JMeter can't copy-paste to and from JMeter and Windows 10

Tags: java, jmeter, windows-10

I met a bizarre issue on my working laptop. Usually, I use my desktop PC for work, but I am in the office today. I am using my working laptop. For some reason, I cannot copy from Windows 10 to JMeter and from JMeter to Windows 10. For example, I am using Notepad++ for creating test cases for interface testing. I am trying to copy-paste from Notepad++ to JMeter. It is not possible.

Something that is very strange for me is that JMeter window has some strange green line at the edge of the window.
[image]
[image]

I am using JMeter version 5.5
Windows 10 - 64 bit
I tried with JDK 17.0.1 and JDK 1.8_202 (because I wasn't sure if the issue came from Java at all)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's connected with JMeter by any means, most probably it's some form of [antivirus software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antivirus_software) which prevents clipboard actions somehow.

You can try [increasing JMeter's logging verbosity to DEBUG level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) just in case and see if there are any suspicious entries in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), however I'm more than sure that the behaviour is caused by some 3rd-party software running on your laptop, if it's not the antivirus it could be something like [WRITEit application](https://writeit.en.softonic.com/) so do a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd) and the issue will go away and then add the startup programs and start services one by one unless you detect the one which causes this problem

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I will connect with the sys admins for help. Maybe it is from the antivirus software.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with JMeter 5.5 when I had changed Option->LookAndFeel->"Metal". Then I returned back to "System" and the problem had gone. Now copy-paste are working well.

Comment: Good to know. My problem was with antivirus software, but it is good to know that there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution.
@Dmitri T was right. The issue appears because of antivirus protection. The fix was to run the jmeter.bat file as an administrator.